# Subprocess fails to catch the standard output

Tags: python, subprocess, biopython

I am trying to generate tree with fasta file input and Alignment with MuscleCommandline

```
import sys,os, subprocess
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
cline = MuscleCommandline(input="c:\Python26\opuntia.fasta")
child= subprocess.Popen(str(cline),
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        shell=(sys.platform!="win32"))
align=AlignIO.read(child.stdout,"fasta")
outfile=open('c:\Python26\opuntia.phy','w')
AlignIO.write([align],outfile,'phylip')
outfile.close()
```

I always encounter with these problems

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 244, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Python26\muscleIO.py", line 11, in <module>
    align=AlignIO.read(child.stdout,"fasta")
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\Bio\AlignIO\__init__.py", line 423, in read
    raise ValueError("No records found in handle")
ValueError: No records found in handle
```

Comment: Helps to state the language (I think its python) as use the code format to make it readable. Also which line is not working and what is the error?

Comment: Look at your edit in preview before posting - the code is now not in code format and is harder to read.

Comment: Maybe this question belongs to BioStar (http://biostar.stackexchange.com) instead of Stack Overflow. FOr me it seems that the problem is in the output of whatever program MuscleCommandline calls.

Comment: @mizipzor, refer to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @SilentGhost, I thought I did. Not fully, since I didnt want to make the code *to* different. Just more consistent. What parts of the PEP do you consider important? Surely my edit is better than the one reverted to?

Comment: Try capturing the output of the child process by replacing "align=AlignIO.read()" with

    f=open( "testfile.fasta" )
    f.write( child.stdout.read() )
    f.close()

That way you can verify if the stream being fed to AlignIO is valid, or maybe contains errors, or is empty, or something.

Comment: @mizipzor: use of `=` with keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biopython 1.54 was released today with a stable version of the Bio.Phylo module. I've updated the documentation with an example pipeline for generating trees. For simplicity, the example uses ClustalW to align sequences and generate a tree, instead of Muscle and Phylip, but most of the code is still the same or similar.

http://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo#Example_pipeline

If you've already generated a tree with Phylip (using the .phy alignment as input), you can still follow the Phylo examples in general. Phylip creates a Newick file with a name like "outttree" or "foo.tree".

(Feel free to merge this with Brad's answer; I can't write a comment in that thread yet.)

Comment: Is Biopython 1.54 beta version? And i am wondering in your example whether it should be input or infile. Because input parameter doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: Can i save this phylo newick tree as a picture?

Comment: For ClustalW the parameter is infile, not input. (Sorry)

To save the tree as a picture, use something like (fixing the whitespace):


    import pylab;
    Phylo.draw_graphviz(tree);
    pylab.show();
    pylab.savefig("egfr-family.png")

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things are giving problems here:

1. You need a child.wait() after the subprocess call so that your code will wait until the external program is done running.
2. Muscle does not actually write to stdout, even though the help documentation says it does, at least with v3.6 that I have here. I believe the latest is v3.8 so this may be fixed.

Biopython is telling you that the stdout you are passing it is empty, which is the error you are seeing. Try running the commandline directly:

```
muscle -in opuntia.fasta
```

and see if you see FASTA output. Here is a version that fixes the wait problem and uses an intermediate output file:

```
import sys,os, subprocess
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
out_file = "opuntia.aln"
cline = MuscleCommandline(input="opuntia.fasta", out=out_file)
child= subprocess.Popen(str(cline),
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        shell=(sys.platform!="win32"))
child.wait()
with open(out_file) as align_handle:
    align=AlignIO.read(align_handle,"fasta")
outfile=open('opuntia.phy','w')
AlignIO.write([align],outfile,'phylip')
outfile.close()
os.remove(out_file)
```

Comment: Now i understand the problem thanks for your help. The opuntia.phy file has been generated, can i draw phylogenetic tree from it? If yes then what drawing phylip module i can use. I have found phyloxml tutorials regarding drawing trees but my output is not .xml

Comment: You've only done an alignment (and then converted the format) and have not yet built a phylogenetic tree. Phylogenetics is a huge topic but here a Python tutorial with PyCogent using Muscle for alignment and FastTree for building the tree: http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2009/12/pycogent-14-fasttree.html

Comment: What im trying to do is:- 1) Take fasta input and do MSA (Muscle) and output alignment file (.phy or .aln) 2) Perform phylogency neighbor joining method (NJ,UPGMA) using phylip  3) And Create tree. Finally my results can be viewed as- MSA, phylogency and tree I haven't used PyCogent so i am trying to complete this project with Biopython right now

Comment: and with open() is not supported in python 2.5.*

Comment: Give the EMBASSY wrappers for phylip a try, as they provide a nice command line interface: http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/release/6.2/embassy/phylipnew/fneighbor.html. There are not wrapper classes in Biopython, but you can generate the command line directly and use subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of the [subproccess library](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> Warning
>
> Use communicate() rather than
>   .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
>   .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to
>   any of the other OS pipe buffers
>   filling up and blocking the child
>   process.

so maybe you could try something like:

```
mydata = child.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an unprotected backslash in your output filename, that is never good.

Use 'r' to get raw strings, i.e. `r'c:\Python26\opuntia.phy'`.

Comment: Or use os.join to join parts of paths